# View controller with 2 destinations

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have 2 buttons in a view controller. If button 1 is clicked, then go to WebView controller. If button 2 is clicked then go to ArtView controller.

How to make `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` have 2 destinations depending on the button clicked?

Answer (score 2):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? WebViewController {
        // your code
    }
    if let destination = segue.destination as? ArtViewController {
        // your code
    }
}
```

Hope it will help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have each button invoke a different segue, either by control-dragging segues directly from the button, or by calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` from your buttons' IBAction code.

Then use code in `prepare(for:sender:)` to figure out which destination is being invoked.

You can:

1. Check the identifier on the segue (not recommended - fragile)
2. Check the class of the destination view controller (better than 1)
3. Have each view controller implement a protocol and check the protocol of the destination:

---

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.destination { 
       case let webView as WebViewProtocol:
         //Your code for a web view
       case let artView as ArtViewProtocol:
         //Your code for an Art View
    }
}
```

Option 3 is reliable while providing loose coupling (each case can trigger any view controller that conforms to the desired protocol. All it needs to know is that the destination understands the desired protocol.)